# jQuery Selector looping array not working

Tags: jquery-selectors

I have a sample page at [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Chandregowda/3VbXM/) which loads audio (HTML5) and have 3 buttons to mute the audio, out of which 3rd button does not mute audio.

Working button events:-

```
$("#domToggle").click(function(){
  document.getElementById('background_audio').muted = document.getElementById('background_audio').muted ? false : true;
});
$("#jQueryToggle").click(function(){
  $('#background_audio')[0].muted = $('#background_audio')[0].muted ? false : true;
});
```

Below button event does not mute:-

```
$("#jQueryToggleWaste").click(function(){
  $('#background_audio').muted = $('#background_audio').muted ? false : true;
});
```

Why does `$('#background_audio').muted` does not loop and change value to every element of the array (which is single element array in this case)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jQuery object returned by the **$** function does not implement the HTML5 muted attribute. That's why the following expression has no effect:

```
$('#background_audio').muted = $('#background_audio').muted ? false : true;
```

Try this instead to change the attribute value for every element of the array:

```
$("#jQueryToggleWaste").click(function () {
    $('#background_audio').each(function () {
        this.muted = !this.muted;
    });
});
```

Comment: `this.muted = !this.muted`

Comment: @StephenThomas: Very well observed. I just updated my answer to use your suggestion ;)